# Count the number of `TRUE` in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list as such

```
$`1`
[1] TRUE

$`5`
[1] TRUE

$`14`
[1] FALSE

$`17`
[1] TRUE

$`19`
[1] TRUE

$`20`
[1] TRUE
```

Is there an easy way to count the total number of **TRUE** values in the list?
I tried doing this `trucount <- function(z){sum(z,na.rm = TRUE)}` , but it doesn't work.

In the above example, the solution would return **5**

Comment: Use `sum(unlist(z))`. That will turn the list into a vector and then you can just `sum` to get the number of true values.

Comment: `unlist` and not `inlist`, @MrFlick! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isTRUE()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html):

```
> ll = list(`1`=TRUE, `5`=TRUE, `14`=TRUE, `17`=TRUE, `19`=TRUE, `20`=TRUE, `21`=FALSE)
> length(which(sapply(ll, isTRUE)))
[1] 6
```